# Unique Solution differential equation system/ linear limited

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I have the following differential equation system:

$$\begin{align}
x'(t)&=\sqrt{1+x^2} +y^3 \sin x -x^7\\
y'(t)&=x(1-y^2 \sin x)
\end{align}$$
with $  x(0)=x_0, \ y(0)=y_0$

I have to show, that $ \forall t \geq 0 $ the System has a unique solution:

I have to show, that the right hand side is linear limited:
$|f(t,x,y)|\leq a(t) + b(t)|(x,y)| $
Can somebody explain me, how I manage to do that?

Comment: Thank you for editing:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions are indeed bounded, as the graphic below demonstrates. To get a theoretical proof of that, consider the radius square $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ so that along solutions you get for $v(t)=V(x(t),y(t))$
\begin{align}
v'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)=2(xx'+yy')
&=2\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2}-x^8+xy\right)\\
&\le (1+2x^2)+(x^2+y^2)\le 1+3v(t),
\end{align}
using $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ twice. This differential inequality provides not exactly the boundedness of the solutions, but an exponential bound for the growth of solutions,
$$
v(t)\le(\tfrac13+v(0))e^{3t}-\tfrac13.
$$
As the solutions can thus not diverge to infinity in finite time, they are defined for all times.

[image: stream plot]

```
def eqn(x,y): return (1+x**2)**0.5+y**3*np.sin(x)-x**7, x*(1-y**2*np.sin(x))

# generate streamplot
r = 5
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-r, r+.01, 0.1), np.arange(-r, r+.05, 0.1))

dotX, dotY = eqn(X,Y)

plt.streamplot(X, Y, dotX, dotY, density=2.5)
plt.xlim(-r,r); plt.ylim(-r,r);
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. V is the solution of my problem? Can I argument without knowing V, because at the moment we are not able to solve differential equation systems.

Comment: I dont get it. How do you know that the solution is bounded by V? Where is the expression sin x, which was in my system?

Comment: No, $(x(t),y(t))$ is the solution, $v(t)=r(t)^2=x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ is the square of the distance to the origin. A bound on $v$ is thus also a bound on the size of the solution. The sine terms cancel in the sum $xx'+yy'$.

Comment: I see. You showed: $ v'(t)\leq 1+3 v(t)$ Can i apply  Grönwall's inequality. Then i would get: v(t) is bounded on each compact set.

Comment: Yes, the next step is then $\left[e^{-3t}(\tfrac13+v(t))\right]'\le 0$, so that $e^{-3t}(\frac13+v(t))\le(\frac13+v(0))$. I'll add the missing $1/3$.

Comment: Can i argument like that?

Comment: Yes, you can argue like that. By the form of the sine terms, I would think it is also the expected form of the solution of the task.

Comment: Where does the inequality $ [e^{-3t}( \frac{1}{3} +v(t))]' \leq 0$ come from? By using the  Grönwall's inequality. I also that v is boundet on each compact set. So my original solution is also bounded. Do I have to show this?

Comment: Nyes, you could use Grönwall, but here it is just the application of the integrating factor $e^{-3t}>0$.

Comment: Aha:) How can I show this?

Comment: You just compute the derivative, $\left[e^{-3t}(\tfrac13+v(t))\right]'=e^{-3t}\left[v'-(1+3v)\right]\le 0$.

Comment: I mean the following: v is bounded, then (x,y) is bounded. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: As $v=r^2$ you get $|x|\le \sqrt{v}$ and $|y|\le \sqrt{v}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help LutzL:) Now everthing is clear. Thank you very much:)